# Im trying to make a maths quiz on python but it says a speech mark is a Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.2

```
            print ("Congratulations for Completing the School Subject Quiz.")
            print (" ")
            print ( name  " Your score is " + score )
            print (" ")
            print ("Thank you very much for taking your time and completing my quiz")
            print (" ")
            print ("Hope you have a great day ")
```

it says that the second speech mark on Where it tells them there name and there score. Help Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a "+" here: `print ( name +  " Your score is " + score )`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the + between `name` and `" Your score is`

Without that symbol it looks like you are trying to print a variable named `name(space)(quote)(space)Your` - when what you are trying to print is the expression `name (plus) a literal string`

Answer (score 0):

Even better would be f-strings.

```
print ("Congratulations for Completing the School Subject Quiz.\n")
print (f"{name} Your score is {score}\n" )
print ("Thank you very much for taking your time and completing my quiz\n")
print ("Hope you have a great day ")
```